# How does one test item membership in an unordered sequence (C++)?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I've used python for a long time, and I'm just beginning to use C++

In python, if one has a set or a dictionary it is relatively easy to get a boolean value indicating whether or not a particular item is in that sequence using the **in** keyword. 
i.e.

```
a = set(2,4,3)   
if 4 in a  
print "yes, 4 is in a, thank you for asking!"
```

it's much more efficient than doing this:

```
a = [2,3,4]  
for number in a
>if number == 4  
>>return "yes, 4 is in a, thank you for asking!"
```

is there a way to do make a membership test simple and efficient in cpp or do you always have to iterate through some ordered sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have functionality like this in [std::set](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html) and tr1::unordered_set (not yet in C++ standard).

```
#include <set>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
     std::set<int> s;
     s.insert(1);        
     s.insert(2);
     s.insert(4);
     if (s.find(4) != s.end())
          puts("4 found!");
     return 0;
}
```

In reality, if your data set is small, linear search may still be the faster option.

Answer (score 2):

Get to know the C++ Standard Template Library.  The `set` class (and others) has a `find()` method that will return an iterator to an item in the set if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the containers offered by [STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) and their performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Python's method is not "much more efficient" because you don't know the complexity of `in` construct.

In C++ there are many methods of storing data. Binary trees are best for searching.

If you work with numbers like 2,3,4 etc, you may consider having an array of bools, and simply see if `array[4] == true`

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
bool contains(const std::set<T>& a, const T& value) {
    return a.find(value) != a.end();
}

if (contains(a, 4)) {
    std::cout << "A contains 4\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) can determine whether or not an element exists in any unordered container or sequence.  If the sequence is unordered and not stored in a specialized container designed for lookups, it's unlikely you're going to do any better than `O(N)`.